# Why is a symmetric distribution sufficient for the sample mean and variance to be uncorrelated?

Tags: self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, references

While reading, I came across the puzzling statement that the sample mean and variance *are uncorrelated only in symmetric distributions* and there is strong correlation if the distribution is heavily skewed.

First of all, is it true? I already know this holds for the case of a *normal* population, but can that proved for *every* symmetric distribution? Although I think the result is counter-intuitive, I would appreciate simple arguments.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us _where_ you found the statement about the sample mean and variance being independent in symmetric distributions?

Comment: It is on page 425 of Hogg and Craig's Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, 7th edition.

Comment: Relevant threads on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111129/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/235634/321264.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

- It is not true that sample mean and variance are always independent if the distribution is symmetric.  For example, take a sample from a distribution which takes values $\pm1$ with equal probability: if the sample mean is $\pm1$ then the sample variance will be $0$, while if the sample mean is not $\pm1$ then the sample variance will be positive.
- It is true that the distributions of the sample mean and variance have zero correlation (if they have a correlation) if the distribution is symmetric.  This is because $E(s_X^2|\bar{X}-\mu=k)=E(s_X^2|\bar{X}-\mu=-k)$ by symmetry.

Neither of these points deal with the statement in the book, which says *only if* but not *if*.

For an example of the final statement, if most of a distribution is closely clustered but there can be the occasional particular very large value, then the sample mean will be largely determined by the number of very large values in the sample, and the more of them there are, the higher the sample variance will be too, leading to high correlation.

Comment: I take it that you looked up the book?

Comment: No - just what you have said in the question

Comment: Thank you, I think that the conditional expectation you outline more or less sums it.

Comment: Part of this answer is unfortunately not correct. In the  first part you talk about *independence* but the question doesn't ask about independence, it asks about zero correlation. It's not sufficient to show they're not independent when proving zero correlation, since variables can be dependent but have zero correlation.

Comment: @Glen_b Henry clearly stated the assumption you are picking on: "if they have a correlation." I suspect you may have overlooked this parenthetical remark when you asserted the second part of the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @whuber You're correct; I overlooked it; The second part of the answer is correct. I'll remove the incorrect part of the comment. My apologies to Henry on that part.

Comment: @Glen_b: I am well aware that zero correlation does not imply independence.  In fact my two bullet points were designed to show this difference. By the way, looking at your deleted answer, I thought about the Cauchy example in your second half and so said "if they have a correlation", while your first half deals with the "only if" point which my mine did not (the question seemed confused about this); so you might think about undeleting it.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your kind words. The first half of my answer unfortunately needs some correction which I was unable to fix then because I needed to sleep. I thought it better to delete it until I could fix its flaws. [I also had no doubt you well understood the difference between independence and zero correlation; I imagine you know your stuff better than me -- I was more concerned about the impression given by the answer. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something about your answer, but then I imagine it's likely some others will as well, so it might be good to clarify with respect to that.]